# Skip optional Parameters within R

Tags: r, parameters, lm

Is this possible?

I am trying to get to the na.exclude parameter within lm() without specifying any parameters in between.

Comment: Qwerty, someone who copied my answer used an extra account to downvote it and and upvote his copy of my answer. As such, I deleted my answer, so let me reply to your question in the comment here -- yes, so skip it you just leave it blank. No need to reference it at all.

Comment: Yea, I saw the -1 for no reason. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By naming an argument in your function call, you can specify it directly without having to specify every other argument that comes before it in the function signature.

```
# don't have to specify everything before na.action
lm(y ~ x, data=df, na.action=na.exclude)
```

(Btw the argument is `na.action`, not `na.exclude`.)

Comment: The `na.exclude` function works fine as well. There's as much reason to believe that's what he meant as the `na.action` argument, but in the end the result is the same anyway.

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense. A function is not an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `na.action`? Sure, optional parameters are optional.

```
y <- rnorm(100, 10)
x <- rbinom(100, 30, .3)
x[x=5] <- NA
lm(y~x, na.action = na.exclude)
```